# How to change the position of the search button in Leanback's BrowseSupportFragment

Tags: android, leanback

I'm using the BrowseSupportFragment from Google's Leanback library, and am having significant trouble changing the placement of the Search Orb View. I know that they must be defining the placement of the search icon in some file, but I can't track it down.

This is what I have now:
[image]

This is what we need:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacky workaround I found, add this to your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Widget.Leanback.SearchOrbViewStyle">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">770dp</item>
    <item name="searchOrbIcon">?attr/defaultSearchIcon</item>
    <item name="searchOrbColor">?attr/defaultSearchColor</item>
    <item name="searchOrbIconColor">?attr/defaultSearchIconColor</item>
    <item name="searchOrbBrightColor">?attr/defaultSearchBrightColor</item>
</style>
```